# SQL creating overview for data that does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a script that will give me a total sum of amounts per sort for the past 3 days and upcoming week.
I have made a [script (link to dbfiddle.uk)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=40be754fb87f01b67ffdc35487844e27) that will sum the amount of the grouped date and sort types. However I am unclear on how to move forward at this point.

I want the past 3 days and upcoming 7 days of the today's date (dynamically), not just the dates found in my table. 
I also want to show all the sort types.

So if there are no records for the date and sort type, show 0 as result.

**plannings table**

```
id  date        cell_id farmer_id
1   2020-04-21  1       1
2   2020-04-22  1       1
3   2020-04-24  1       1
4   2020-04-21  2       1
5   2020-04-22  2       1
6   2020-04-23  1       1
7   2020-04-25  1       1
8   2020-04-26  1       1
9   2020-04-22  4       1
10  2020-04-21  4       1
11  2020-04-23  4       1
```

**planning_amounts table**

```
id  planning_id sort_type_id    amount
2   1           1               43
3   1           3               34
4   2           1               54
5   3           1               45
6   4           1               90
7   5           3               45
8   5           1               99
9   6           1               66
10  7           1               999
11  8           3               90
12  9           1               23
13  10          1               43
14  11          1               55
```

**sort_types table**

```
id  name        description
1   Fijn        Fijn
2   Middel      Middel
3   Reuze       Reuze
4   Industrie   Industrie
```

**The expected result would look like this.** *(this obviously for the past 3 + upcomming 7 days)*

```
amount  description date
176     Fijn        2020-04-21
34      Reuze       2020-04-21
0       Middel      2020-04-21
0       Industrie   2020-04-21
176     Fijn        2020-04-22
45      Reuze       2020-04-22
0       Middel      2020-04-22
0       Industrie   2020-04-22
121     Fijn        2020-04-23
0       Reuze       2020-04-23
0       Middel      2020-04-23
0       Industrie   2020-04-23
```

**Query**

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as amount, a.date, c.description
FROM planning_amounts b
join plannings a ON b.planning_id = a.id
join (SELECT * from sort_types) c ON b.sort_type_id = c.id
group by date, c.description
order by date
```

Comment: To force the inclusion of rows for all dates in your desired range, you will need to fabricate the dates in some fashion. Search for calendar table to find ways to do that. Generally speaking, it is both good and efficient to have an actual calendar table (rather than dynamically generating one for every usage) - a topic that can also be found in your searching. With the calendar, you simply outer join from it to your source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understood your question a bit better now:

```
WITH DesiredDates AS 
(SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd,-3,GETDATE()) as DATE) AS DesiredDate UNION ALL
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd,-2,GETDATE()) as DATE) UNION ALL
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()) as DATE) UNION ALL
 SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) UNION ALL
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd,1,GETDATE()) as DATE) UNION ALL
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd,2,GETDATE()) as DATE) UNION ALL
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd,3,GETDATE()) as DATE) UNION ALL
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd,4,GETDATE()) as DATE) UNION ALL
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd,5,GETDATE()) as DATE) UNION ALL
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd,6,GETDATE()) as DATE) UNION ALL
 SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd,7,GETDATE()) as DATE) 
), DesiredDatesAndSortTypes AS (
SELECT * FROM DesiredDates CROSS JOIN (select id from sort_types) t
) 
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Amount,0)) as Amount, DesiredDate, c.Description 
FROM planning_amounts b
join plannings a ON b.planning_id = a.id
right join DesiredDatesAndSortTypes ddst ON CAST(a.date as DATE)=ddst.DesiredDate and b.sort_type_id=ddst.id
join sort_types c ON ddst.id = c.id
GROUP BY ddst.DesiredDate,c.Description 
ORDER BY DesiredDate,Description
```

Here's the fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c508639ba4ec5bd49b49c9afe0692c9f

If I missunderstood yet again, please clarify where :)

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but this is not what my question asks

Comment: Gave it another shot :)
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c508639ba4ec5bd49b49c9afe0692c9f

Comment: Great! I will give it some polishing, but this is exactly what I am looking for.Cheers

Comment: After tweaking some things and doing some tests, I realised this does not take different users (farmer_id) into consideration. I have tried making it so it would only show results per user rather then everyone. But this stops the insertion of the empty date/sort types

Comment: the main idea here is where you create the  DesiredDatesAndSortTypes. This table contains your relevant columns except the amounts that you compute. You need to add the users there as well if you want to group by user too.

Comment: Yeh I had a bit of a brainfart writing this message. I looked at it with a second eye and realised all i needed to do was change the `join plannings a` to `join (select * from plannings where farmer_id = '$currentFarmer->id') a`. (If anyone reads this and wants the sql equivalent to this, just change the `'$currentFarmer->id'` to an int)

Comment: Tried it here, but the data contains only one farmer.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fcb40739ae35acc75c304a13f84fd3d5